# I am having trouble to delete individual document from my firebase firestore database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a react app which lists book titles and author names. The data stores in firebase firestore database and it sync with the application at frontend. The problem I am having is that to delete individual document from the collection. I'm able to access the id but unable to single out particular id to delete. I put the code below and hoping somebody can helping me out to show how I should delete individual document, at the moment it deletes all the documents.  Thanks!

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import firebase from '../config/fbConfig'


const useBooks = () => {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
     useEffect(() => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('books').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const newBooks =  snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                 id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
              }))
            setBooks(newBooks)
        })
    },[])
    return books
}

const handleOnClick = () => { 
    const db = firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('books').get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            const id = doc.id
            db.collection('books').doc(id).delete() 
            console.log("Jampa thinlay Book ID:", id)
        }) 

    })     
}

const BookList = () => {
    const books = useBooks()
    console.log('jt books', books)
    return(
        <div className="book_list">
            <ul>
                {
                    books.map(book => 
                         <li key={book.id} onClick={()=> handleOnClick()} >
                            <div className="title">id:{book.id}</div>
                            <div className="cross" > X </div>
                            <div className="title">book:{book.title.title}</div>
                            <div className="author">author: {book.author.author}</div>
                         </li>      
                    )
                } 
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default BookList
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that in your function

```
const handleOnClick = () => { 
    const db = firebase.firestore()
    db.collection('books').get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            const id = doc.id
            db.collection('books').doc(id).delete() 
            console.log("Jampa thinlay Book ID:", id)
        }) 

    })     
}
```

you are looping all the documents, and are calling delete on each of them, which then your issue happens.

a solution to this would be to change the signature of your `handleOnClick` function to recieve the id of the item to be deleted, like so

```
const handleOnClick = (documentId) => { 
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    db.collection("books").doc(documentId).delete()
           .then(() => {
             console.log("item with id" + documentId + "got deleted");
            }).catch((e) => console.log(e));   
}
```

the difference of the new function is that it receive the `id` of the document you want to delete, and deletes only that document,

and in your html you can pass the id of each book as follows

```
const BookList = () => {
    const books = useBooks()
    console.log('jt books', books)
    return(
        <div className="book_list">
            <ul>
                {
                    books.map(book => 
                         <li key={book.id} onClick={()=> handleOnClick(book.id)} > // <-----------------
                            <div className="title">id:{book.id}</div>
                            <div className="cross" > X </div>
                            <div className="title">book:{book.title.title}</div>
                            <div className="author">author: {book.author.author}</div>
                         </li>      
                    )
                } 
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```